slim framework firebase push notification
I'm using the Slim framework as a PHP API and I'm sending Firebase push notifications on my website. The problem is that when I try to add data to the notification, I receive two notifications for a single send. Can you help me, please?
I'm using the Slim framework as a PHP API and I'm sending Firebase push notifications on my website. The problem is that when I try to add data to the notification, I receive two notifications for a single send.



Please don't screenshots of code or other textual content, but rather post them as actual text and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark them up. Having the content as text makes it accessible, searchable and makes it easier for folks to help you. Also see: Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?
